# Derive the pdf/cdf of a variable given as a formula of two random variables

Tags: data-transformation, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

Let's assume I have two random variables ***X*** and ***Y*** with ***x>0*** and ***y>0***, respectively. Let's also assume that their marginals are known as well as the joint cdf is known as the product of the two marginals (independent variables).

How would I find the pdf of a 3rd variable ***Z*** for which:

log(Z) = X - log(Y) - 3.5

I am assuming I can start from: $P(Z\leq z)=P(log(Z)\leq log(z))=P(X-log(Y)-3.5\leq log(z))=P(X\leq log(z)+log(Y)+3.5)$

Then integrate the joint $f_{XY}(x,y)$ in the region $x\geq log(z)+log(y)+3.5$.

Does this make sense? Can I use the above expression in the limit of my integral?

Comment: If you do not know the joint pdf, the question cannot be answered.

Comment: Let's assume the joint is the product of the two marginals, i.e., independent variables...

Comment: The general approach is illustrated in many related threads: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=distribution+function+joint+variable.  Although you could use the right hand side of the inequality as the limit of an integral (after checking for typographical errors, because you seem to have reversed its direction), you still have to indicate somewhere that $x\gt 0,$ lest you obtain an erroneous answer.  Many people find it useful to sketch a plot of the region of integration--it helps avoid such errors.